# ICMP source field

Tags: networking, ip, ping, icmp

I would assume that **Echo Request** must be always have the IP address in the source field in order that the destination knows where to send a response packet, yet in the following question (from Stanford's online networking course):

`Which of the following ICMP Messages will always have a router’s IP address in the source field?`

**Echo Request** was not considered a correct answer. Why?

Comment: Only IP packets sourced by the router will have the router's IP address in the source address field. The source address field of an IP packet contains the IP address of the host that sourced the packet. There is nothing in the packet that has a router address, unless the router is the source or destination of the packet.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](http://www.danzig.jct.ac.il/tcp-ip-lab/ibm-tutorial/3376c24.html#icmp8) the echo request won't contain any IP addresses. About the destination address to send response, the response can be sent using the IP address it came from (which is the source IP in IP protocol). The question asks for the IP address in ICMP message only. But you are confusing it with IP source address.